# New radio plays quiet

Tags: pontiac, audio

I have a Pontiac G6, and the factory CD player stopped working. My sister bought a JVC system with a kit and adapter. When she installed it, the audio was quiet. Everything seemed to be wired correctly. What could be wrong?

Comment: I take it, the new system powers up, but no sound comes out? Is there a factory amp which is not getting powered on when the stereo is powered?

Comment: How can I determine if the amp is/isn't getting power?

Comment: I guess you'd have to find the amp (if it exists) first. Then check the wires to ensure it's getting power. There is probably a separate wire in the harness which is not being attached to anything. Your new stereo should have a separate wire (which is not getting used at this time) which is there to energize amps if present. It's going to take some troubleshooting to figure it out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was wrong about the wiring. The speakers were wired to subwoofer outputs instead of the mains.